# Is that safe to assign capture lambda function to std::function<>?

Tags: c++

I am facing a weird issue when running the following code compiled using [1]

It looks like a capture lambda function assigned to `std::function<>` does not work properly.

Why is that?

---

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    std::function<void()> func_test_1;
};
A::A() {
    printf("This in constructor: 0x%lx\n", this);
    auto func_auto = [this]() {
        printf("This in lambda: 0x%lx\n", this);
    };
    func_test_1 = func_auto;
    func_auto();    //this is correct
    func_test_1();  //this not correct
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
    return 0;
}
```

---

More infos:

The above code runs well on PC ubunbu, but failed to run on a Arm Board, and finally I found it is due to the -o2 compile option, here is the details:

Bad run result with the following compile:

(...)/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7ve -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -pipe -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall --sysroot=(...)sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi -s -O2 -rdynamic -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp

Run:

This in constructor: 0x26f1c

This in lambda: 0x26f1c

This in lambda: 0x1c

Correct run result with the following compile:(without the -o2)

(...)/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7ve -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -pipe -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall --sysroot=(...)sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi -s -rdynamic -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp

Run:

This in constructor: 0x27f1c

This in lambda: 0x27f1c

This in lambda: 0x27f1c

[1]
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ (GCC) 6.2.0

Comment: Probably not the problem here, but your program have *undefined behavior* because you print a pointer with wrong `printf` format. Either use the correct format to print a `void*` (yes, casting is really needed) which is `"%p"`, or stop using `printf` and use `std::cout` which is type-safe.

Comment: "_does not work_" - Care to describe in what way it does not work?

Comment: I'm getting the same memory address for all cases.

Comment: Exactly this result.

Comment: You capture the pointer.  Why do you expect the value of the pointer to change doing that?

Comment: I'm just saying that's working as expected...

Comment: Hi, guys, thanks for the comments. I should have given more info on this. Just update the orignal question

Comment: It should not be the print issue, print is just to show captured "this" not work as expected. The orignal is a segment fault in a large program which try to access this->xxx in its code, I just simplified to above code snip to be more clear on the description.-_-

Comment: Did you try the combination `-O3 -fno-schedule-insns2` too? It's not fun to run totally unoptimized :-)